# Adding built in Google search capability to browser

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to give my simple browser the ability to recognize that text with spaces should be treated as a google search query.  To create a string that can go into a url I need to replace the spaces with "+"s.

I have attempted to do this in the first "if" statement however when I do run the program and put text with spaces into the search bar nothing happens; entering "google.com" or other urls work though.

What is wrong with my code?

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    NSString *URLString = textField.text;

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];

   if ([URLString rangeOfString:@" "].location != NSNotFound) {
    NSString *plusReplace = [URLString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
    URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"google.com/search?q=<%@ query", plusReplace]];


    }

    if (!URL.scheme) {
        // The user didn't type http: or https:
        URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", URLString]];
    }

    if (URL) {
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
        [self.webView loadRequest:request];

    }

    return NO;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have an issue with the 3rd conditional making a 2nd request. What if you change it to this?

```
if (URL) {
    NSString *plusReplace = [URLString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
    URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"google.com/search?q=<%@ query", plusReplace]];
}

if (!URL.scheme) {
    // The user didn't type http: or https:
    URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", URLString]];
}

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Functionality still doesn't work with the changes that you made, thanks for pointing out the double conditional though.

Comment: Do you have a way to figure what is being requested when a submission with spaces is made? That would be the first thing I would check for if I was debugging this.

Comment: I don't know what the program does when a submission with spaces is made, I'll have to find that out.

Comment: After taking a second look at this, I think the problem is that when you check to see if the URL is missing the protocol prefix you are prepending it to the original string and not the one where you reformatted it for a Google query. Can you try and check if adding `http://` right before `google.com...` fixed things?